# Laravel - Can't receive request

Tags: php, curl

I have a function which receives the signal from another server using cURL. I've been trying like this to process that cURL. It is a JSON btw.

```
public function receiveSignal(Request $request)
    {
        $json = file_get_contents($request->getContent());

        $data = json_decode($json, true);
    }
```

But when I try `curl -X POST http://123.45.8.1/api/myPage`

I get an error.
Also I tried with `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`.. still not working. My method type is GET... I tried with both GET and POST in cURL.

**EDIT**

This is the error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: 
>   in file
>   /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
>   on line 255

Thanks

Comment: post the error.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: post also the rows n. 255

Comment: show your route url

Comment: My route url is - `Route::get('/api/myPage', 'SignalController@receiveSignal');`

Comment: The error is correct, you are trying to `POST` to a route previously declared as `GET` in Laravel routes.

Comment: I am POSTing to GET method... But if I change in my cURL to GET, and method to POST it is still the same.

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying `GET`?

Comment: You have to use the same on both

Comment: what happen if you try `curl -X GET http://123.45.8.1/api/myPage`

Comment: Same thing. As response I am getting a bunch of HTML elements...

Comment: Ok, it works with GET, but I need POST method...

Answer (score -2):

Did you check you route for eg in route (web.php)

```
  Route:: get('someurl',controller@function);
```

And from your view you try to call post method then this error occur
Method should same in both end